# Bottom space won't disappear after setting constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

I have an application where the storyboard looks like this: 
[image]

In the output the user can scroll between the two tableViewControllers (using the pageViewController, who is embedded in a container).

I set the constrains of the container to (top:50, right:0, bottom:0, left:0, not relative to margin). I also tried to set the "heightForFooterInSection" in both tableViews to 0 and CGFLOAT_MIN, but the bottom spacing won't disappear. This is my output:

[image]

Any suggestions? I'm sure there's an obvious solution I'm missing but I can't figure out which one.

Comment: So you _want_ to leave all that empty space at the top, but you don't want to leave empty space at the bottom?

Comment: Why not debug? Use the View Debugger! It will tell you exactly what you're seeing and what is positioning and sizing the views on the screen.

Comment: Correct, I don't want to leave the empty space at the bottom. I am new to objectiveC/cocoa programming so I never used the View Debugger, but I will try to figure it out right now. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, let me know how you get on. It's impossible to see your storyboard from here, so it really is better if you try to analyze this from your end.

Comment: Wow, that was easy :)! If only I knew this tool existed two weeks ago, that would've saved me a lot of time up until today. Turns out I just had to remove the page control (presentationCountForPageViewController and
presentationIndexForPageViewController methods). Thanks again matt!

Comment: Aaaaagh! I should have thought of this. Yes, the page control has a horrible feature: by default it is white-on-white. That's why we couldn't see it, even though that is what was taking up the space. But of course the View Debugger just showed it to you directly! Is it cool or what?

Comment: You should answer your own question. Surely this will be useful to someone some day...! After 48 hours you can accept your own answer to your own question and close the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by removing the page control, i.e. removing the following UIPageViewControllerDataSource methods:

```
-(NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:
-(NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:
```

The page control is white-on-white by default, that is why I missed it.

Thanks to @matt, who pointed out to me I should use the View Debugger, this was an easy catch.

I hope this will help!